# Good practice(s) for breaking Maven build when specific class members change values between release versions

Tags: java, maven

In an on-going Java-language Maven multi-module project with periodic new version releases, some constant values need to remain constant in the source code with respect to time, even across ensuing new versions. These constants are patterned as such:

```
public static final String GREMLIN_VITALITY_EXCITED_DB_FIELD_KEY = "excited";
```

If a developer comes along to a value that has already shipped in code to production and changes that value and the change makes it into future shipping deliverables, ensuing releases will carry the changed values and wreak havoc, potentially causing data loss and upsetting customers. I seek to render these constants unsusceptible to change by developers, even through newer releases.

Why you might ask? One particular area I am currently looking at is ensuring that values are correct for their particular DB schema versions in a DB upgrade system that executes a cumulative upgrade by version steps, where specific constants are relied upon and must not change. Another area is, similarly, certain values passed in the REST API.

I'm looking for an effective technical solution, preferably a dead-simple one, that assists in systemically eliminating the ability to change, or at least automate detection of forbidden changes to, a set of Java language constant values (as above), and preferably during the Maven build so that the production line would be stopped for all developers until corrected.

There are of course code reviews to help sieve this class of transgression, albeit being performed by fallible humans. Each of us only trusts ourselves and each other so far; an automated system of prevention (or, we'll grudgingly accept mere detection) will satisfy the remaining, unaddressed parts of our risk tolerance profile.

Things we've considered so far:

- Experiment with language constructs to effect prevention of changes. Found no such thing. Rather quickly. Because source code can be changed, committed, and merged into the release branch.
- Manually curate compiled class files. Trickiness means that the tendency for operational "misses" is not systemically eliminated.
- Quarantine classes that bear forever-constant Java language "constants" into a separate Maven module. The process of curation is more deliberate with file editing and updating Maven dependency GAVs in dependent modules, but still doesn't have the machine detect value changes for us, and remains open to human error.
- Identify Maven mechanisms that solve this issue. Perhaps there is an annotation that we can apply to the appropriate constants, and break the build on failed comparison with prior versions found in the MVN repo? Alas, our Google-fu appears insufficient.
- Employ Clirr to identify unacceptable changes and break the build. But, Clirr seems to detect changes only to interface definitions ("public API").
- If the associated parts of the build system that detect changes are themselves changed, different and appropriate warning signals will trip. Therefore, this scenario doesn't worry us.

Comment: As you outlined yourself in your question: I think there are many many different ways to go about such requirements; thus: there is no "best" solution, you could only hope for a *discussions* of pros/cons here. But SO is not a site for pro/con discussions; but about specific programming questions. Thus dont be surprised if the main feedback you get are downvotes/close requests. Maybe you are lucky and attract real answers; but I doubt it.

Comment: Clirr's warning 6003 ("Value of compile-time constant has changed") seems like what you want, along with 6011 ("removed a constant field").

Comment: For the REST API there is something called [PACT](https://docs.pact.io/) which handles the REST API very well...Furthermore what is the most important the public API...

Comment: We wrote a Maven plugin named Polypara to assist with this.. https://github.com/vivid-inc/polypara

Answer (score 1):

That is **unit testing** is made for. Maven will test the code before build.

Alternatively you can use **.properties** file, and put there all your constant values. So after deployment you can just ensure the one properties file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Move the constants into a separate Maven artifact with its own build-release lifecycle and versioning, separate from your multi-module project build-release lifecycle. Any part of your multi-module project which needs to use the constants will have to use Maven's dependency mechanism to import a specific version of the 'constants' artifact, and you can use dependencyManagement to make it clear that all your modules should use the same version. Your tree of pom's could also be audited (in an automated fashion) to ensure no module 'accidentally' sets its own version.

New versions of the constants artifact should only be released after an extensive review of commits to that part of the SCM, and should be manually triggered when an expected change happens (e.g. a new constant is added).

And then you can put hooks into your SCM alerting the relevant authorities if code in the 'constants' area of the repo changes.